# Print paper from Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Is it possible to print the paper from android app without using Bluetooth and WiFi connectivity? I mean how to integrate the android app with invoice generate printer machine without connecting to Bluetooth and WiFi.

Comment: Without establishing any sort of connection I think it's not possible.

Comment: @AgentP Apart from Bluetooth and WiFi what are the possible ways to establish a connection.

Comment: Yes it is possible, u must have a printer which has usb port opened, and u need to have a cable to connect with the printer, and most important thing is u need the application to establish connection with printer, if not u need to go through the printer brand Solution Portal and download SDK and other sample codes(if u need to develop by yourself).